# How to center block level links within a div

Tags: html, css, centering

This would appear to be super simple, but for some reason I am struggling with this. I have some links that control a jQuery content slider. The links need to be centered at the bottom of the slider. The text of the links are set via the jQuery plugin I am using so I just use `text-indent: -9999px` to hide it and display a background image instead. Each link is set to block and 10px wide and tall. However I cannot get them to be centered within a div. Here's a little diagram of what I want to do.

|                                           • • •                                         |

The 3 bullets represent the links I want to center. I want them to be centered whether or not I have 2 links or 10 links. If I had a set number of links this would probably be a lot easier as I could create a parent with a fixed width and use `margin:0 auto;` on it.

Here's my code so far...

HTML..

```
<div id="pager">
  <a href="#slide1">1</a>
  <a href="#slide2">2</a>
  <a href="#slide3">3</a>
</div>
```

CSS..

```
#pager {float:left; width:100%; display: block; text-align: center;}

#pager a {display:block; width:10px; height:10px; float:left; background-image: url(img/pager-off.gif); text-indent: -9999px; background-color: red; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/h2r6c/

I added a margin to the links, just so see where they started and ended.
Apart from that, get rid of the `float:left` in your link CSS and you're good, provided they aren't block level.  They need to be `display:inline-block` to be side-by-side like you want.

Answer (score 2):

I want this?

http://jsfiddle.net/oswaldoacauan/phXvv/

Answer (score 1):

If by centered you mean each one centered in the middle of the container, and therefore stacked on top of one another, don't float. And the key is margin:auto

```
#pager a {
    display:block; 
    width:10px; height:10px; 
    margin:auto
    background-image: url(img/pager-off.gif); 
    background-color: red; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

If, however, you mean each of the links are side-by-side, and they are centered as a set in the middle of the container, then use display:inline-block on the links, with text-align:center on the container:

```
#pager a {
    display:inline-block; 
    width:10px; height:10px; 
    background-image: url(img/pager-off.gif); 
    background-color: red; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#pager{
    text-align:center;
```